# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2) generate error in console: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix

Tags: ios, ios5

The first time I turn my iphone turns the button. The second time I turn the iphone fails.

```
- (void)configureViewsLandscapeMode
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

        [self.button setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];

    } else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {


        [self.button setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2)];

    }
}
```

I read others similar answers:

[UIView scale to 0 using CGAffineTransformMakeScale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216076/1827690)

[CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12015785/1827690)

I'm starting with IOS and I do not understand the problem. I would like to understand the problem more than having a solution, I would appreciate some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a rotation animation, make sure you are not changing view `frame`. That can happen for example when autoresizing is used or when you are trying to change `frame` explicitely.

If you change frame and transform at the same time, especially inside an animation, iOS tries to generate an animation from the original position to the target position. That involves some matrix calculations and that can end in an error if multiple changes (e.g. `frame`) are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
- (void)configureViewsLandscapeMode
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

        [self.button setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI_2)];

    } else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {


        [self.button setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -M_PI_2)];

    }
}
```